# Did you know - WordPress plugin SEO Ultimate's open Graph Integrator causes a warning?

Tags: wordpress

This took a while to find so I thought I'd post it here...

If you are using CiviCRM in wordpress, and have the "SEO Ultimate" plugin, and its "Open Graph Integrator" module enabled, you may see the following error:

Warning: Missing argument 2 for CiviCRM_For_WordPress::single_page_title() in /home/civicthe/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 1273

I'm not sure if this causes problems in the backend, but I'm hoping its the cause of some of mine.

Fix:
Disable the "Open Graph Integrator" module
Install the similar "WordPress SEO by Yoast" plugin instead - it's open graph module does the same functionality but WITHOUT the error.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Since you discovered a fix, please post that part as an answer to your own question and then accept it. The format is Q&A, and with no A, people won't find your Q...

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in the SEO Ultimate plugin. You should report that they are incorrectly calling:

`apply_filters( 'single_post_title', $post->post_title )`

in three places:

- modules/opengraph/opengraph.php (line 116)
- modules/titles/titles.php (line 179)
- modules/titles/titles.php (line 184)

The call should read:

`apply_filters( 'single_post_title', $post->post_title, $post )`.

Their support page is here:
https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/seo-ultimate